# Trying to understand how functors are implemented in FSharpPlus

Tags: f#, f#+

Can someone explain how this code works in F#:

https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpPlus/blob/master/src/FSharpPlus/Control/Functor.fs#L99-99

```
static member inline Invoke (mapping: 'T->'U) (source: '``Functor<'T>``) : '``Functor<'U>`` = 
    let inline call (mthd: ^M, source: ^I, _output: ^R) = ((^M or ^I or ^R) : (static member Map : (_*_)*_ -> _) (source, mapping), mthd)
    call (Unchecked.defaultof<Map>, source, Unchecked.defaultof<'``Functor<'U>``>)
```

Specifically the `call` function, which uses a syntax which I do not understand

e.g.

- What does `(^M or ^I or ^R)` mean?
- What parts of this are code and what parts are type definitions?
- How does it have a type signature `... -> 'a` when it seems to return a tuple?
- Is there some kind of type level programing hackery going on?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This voodoo syntax is called ["Statically Resolved Type Parameters"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters), or SRTPs for short.

Normal type parameters are denoted with a tick, like `'a`. These type parameters are natively supported by the .NET runtime, so types and functions with such type parameters are compiled directly to classes and methods in IL.

SRTPs are denoted with a circumflex, like `^M`, and are *not* supported by the .NET runtime, and therefore cannot be compiled to IL, and therefore have to be "unrolled" during compilation time. This means that for every use site of thus parametrized function, the compiler must determine what concrete types the SRTPs should be, and insert the whole body of the function at call site, also known as "inlining". This is what the `inline` keyword is for.

The point of SRTPs is to express a constraint saying "*any type that has a method or property with this signature*". In your particular example, this is expressed on this line:

```
    let inline call (mthd: ^M, source: ^I, _output: ^R) = ((^M or ^I or ^R) : (static member Map : (_*_)*_ -> _) (source, mapping), mthd)
               ^^^^        ^^          ^^           ^^     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
               (1)          \----------||-----------/                       (3)                        (4)                  (5)
                                       (2)
```

The line means:

1. Define a function named `call`,
2. With three tupled parameters of types `^M`, `^I`, and `^R` respectively,
3. And make sure that at least one of those types has a static method named `Map`,
4. And that method takes a tuple `(^I * ^R) * ^M`,
5. And we call that method passing it `((source, mapping), mthd)` as parameter.

---

As to why it returns a tuple - it doesn't. The tuple on the last line is not returned from the `Invoke` function, but passed as parameter to the `call` function. It's the result of `call` that is returned from `Invoke`.

Comment: So, (5) is used in two different steps in the invocation: first the types of source/mapping/mthd are used to fully flesh out the signature of (4); second to be applied as function arguments?

Comment: Yes, from (5) `source` and `mapping` values are passed and used in the actual functor implementation, but `mthd` value is not used.